# Use template html page with BaseHttpRequestHandler

Tags: python, html, webserver

I am building a small program with Python, and I would like to have a GUI for some configuration stuff. Now I have started with a BaseHTTPServer, and I am implementing a BaseHTTPRequestHandler to handle GET and POST requests. But I am wondering what would be best practice for the following problem.

I have two separate requests that result in very similar responses. That is, the two pages that I return have a lot of html in common. I could create a template html page that I retrieve when either of these requests is done and fill in the missing pieces according to the specific request. But I feel like there should be a way where I could directly retrieve two separate html pages, for the two requests, but still have one template page so that I don't have to copy this.

I would like to know how I could best handle this, e.g. something scalable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with BaseHTTPRequestHandler as its purpose is to serve HTML, how you generate the HTML is another topic.

You should use a templating tool, there are a lot available for Python, I would suggest using Mako or Jinja2. then, on your code, just get the real HTML using the template and use it on your handler response.

Comment: I had a quick look at Mako. Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it :)